# Unable to receive Ajax post response from server

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongoose

I'm able to see the response sent from the server in the network tab when I 'inspect' the page. However, console doesn't log the response in 'success'. Node.js as the backend. Following is the code :

```
function getFilteredData(){

    $(function( $ ){
        console.log("getting table data");

        var filters ={};     
        //inserted some data in filters
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : "query/get-filtered-data",
            dataType : 'application/json',
            async: "true",
            data:JSON.stringify(filters),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success : function(data){
                console.log(data);
                // doesn't log anything. 
                //server response is visible in networks section of 'inspect' in browser.

            },
            failure: function(data){
                alert('got an error');
            }
        });
    });

}
```

I send 'filters' as the data to the server side. There, I use these filters to query a mongodb collection using mongoose.

```js
router.post('/get-filtered-data', bodyParser.json(), function (req, res) {

  console.log(req.body);
  var filters = req.body;

  // authorModel is my mongoose model.
  authorModel.find({})
    .then(function (doc) {
      console.log(doc);    //prints the correct response
      res.send(doc);      
    });
});
```

Is there anything wrong with the code or am I missing something? Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT:**
Added the function where I make the ajax call. This function is in a  in the HTML file.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @Quentin, it now works. Changed my datatype in the ajax call to `dataType:'json'`.

Comment: any error on frontend ??

Comment: Check the accepted answer here too as well. Might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1

Comment: @xdeepakv No, there isn't any.

Comment: can u add more code.. hard to debug here

Comment: Open the developer tools. Look at the console. Are there any error messages? Open the network tab. Look at the response to `query/get-filtered-data`. Is it what you expect? Does it have a 200 OK status code?

Comment: `dataType : 'application/json',` — That is not a valid value for the `dataType` property. Check the jQuery documentation for a list of valid values.

Comment: @Quentin Yep that was the mistake. `datatype:'json'` was the correct value. Could you post your answer so that I can accept it?